# How would I hide/unhide buttons when pressing on the view?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have these buttons on my cameraView that I want to hide when pressing on the view. I got that to work but I want to unhide the buttons when I press on the view again. How would I be able to do that?

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    
    if touch?.view == self.cameraView {
      
        flipCamera.isHidden = true
        lockButton.isHidden = true
        print("Hide buttons")
    
    } else if touch?.view == self.cameraView && flipCamera.isHidden == true {
        

        print("show buttons")

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `isHidden` value to its opposite on each touch, you can simply use the `toggle()` function, which toggles a `Bool` value - it assigns `false` if the value was `true` and assigns `true` if the value was `false`.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    
    if touch?.view == self.cameraView {
        flipCamera.isHidden.toggle()
        lockButton.isHidden.toggle()
    }
}
```